# How to fix "error code=mustpostparams" on mediawiki-api in Java

Tags: java, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm working on a project which use the mediawiki API and I have this error :

> error code=mustpostparams
>
> > info:'The following parameters were found in the query string, but must be in the POST body: lgpassword, lgtoken.'

This is my code :

```java
Mediawiki wiki=new Mediawiki(site);
Login login=wiki.login(login,password); //error
wiki.edit(title, content , summary);
wiki.logout();
```

To login to my mediawiki I use login action but I think I can use query action.
In the documentation : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tokens I found :

```py
PARAMS = {
    'action':"query",
    'meta':"tokens",
    'type':"login",
    'format':"json"
}
```

I think it's exactly what I need but it's in python and I don't know how to do this in Java. I know that there is a function getQueryResult() but I don't know how to use it.

How to do the query action in Java ?
Thanks

Comment: Is it ```Login login = wiki.login(wiki.prepareLogin(login),login,password);``` ? I have the same error

Comment: With ```Api apiResult = wiki.getActionResult("login", "&lgname=" + login + "&lgpassword=" + password, wiki.prepareLogin(login), null);``` I have the same error too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146687/how-to-fix-readapidenied-error-on-mediawiki-api-in-java/57214862#57214862), both are related :

I just add

```
Mediawiki wiki=new Mediawiki(site);
wiki.setVersion("Mediawiki 1.28"); //New
Login login=wiki.login(login,password);
```

And don't forget to use a bot ! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login