# How to fix "readapidenied" error on mediawiki-api in Java

Tags: java, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm working on a project which use the mediawiki API and I have this error :

> error code=readapidenied info:'You need read permission to use this module.'
>
> > INFOS: Could not retrieve Mediawiki Version via API - will assume Mediawiki 1.27 or before you might want to set the Version actively if you are on 1.28 and have the api blocked for non-logged in users

This is my code :

```java
Mediawiki wiki=new Mediawiki(site);
Login login=wiki.login(login,password); //error
wiki.edit(title, content , summary);
wiki.logout();
```

I know that I have Mediawiki 1.32.1
I tried a lot of variables for the login but I have the same error...

Can you help me to fix this error ? Thanks

Comment: I have the same error when I want to do ```System.out.println(wiki.getVersion());``` but without the "infos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add

```java
Mediawiki wiki=new Mediawiki(site);
wiki.setVersion("Mediawiki 1.28"); //New
Login login=wiki.login(login,password);
```

And don't forget to use a bot !
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login

Comment: Very good you found that out. Things are simpler if you put the details in an ini file and you won't have to bother with the details later. See http://mediawiki-japi.bitplan.com/index.php/CommandLine on how to create an ini file